# How do I get the rows and columns from a tbody in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to apply css classes to a calendar after it's been loaded. I've confirmed everything in the javascript and the method in the controller works as it should until I try to get the rows from the tbody. here's the javascript.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var calendar = $('#Trafikkalender');
    var date = $('#selectedDate').val();
    var param = { date: date }
    var url = $('#calArrayPostUrl').data('url');
    $.post(url, param, function(data) {
        var body = calendar.find('tbody');

        //var rows = body.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        var rows = body.rows;

        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            //var cols = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
            var cols = rows[i].cells;
            for (var j = 0; cols.length; j++) {
                var col = cols[j];
                col.addClass(data[i][j]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

when I hover over rows in the debugger in chrome it dsays that rows is undefined. as you can see I've tried another approach but getElementsByTagName is not a function according to chrome.

Comment: Are you aware that jQuery has an `.addClass()` method?

Comment: look at the bottom of the inner for loop

Comment: If that function is actually defined (which I don't think so) it cannot be `jQuery.addClass()` because `col` is not a jQuery object. I composed an answer with the details.

Comment: ah yes, I have since changed cols. it is now var col = $(cols[j]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this

```
$.post(url, param, function(data) {
    var body = calendar.find('tbody');
    var rows = body.find('tr');

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var cols = $(rows[i]).find('td');
        for (var j = 0; cols.length; j++) {
            var col = cols[j];
            col.addClass(data[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: we are definitely getting somewhere now. had to change var col = cols[j]; to $(cols[j]); and it seems to run fine. but hey... for some reason my data is not a 2-dim array, it got flattened into a 1-dim array, why is that? I have in my controller: string[,] dates = new string[numWeeks,7]; and: return Json(dates); why did it not keep the structure?

Comment: I'm gonna have to make a separate question for this. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find()` method passing the tag name:

```
 var rows = body.find('tr');
```

Same can be used for `td` elements too.

Comment: I thought about that, but I thought it only returns the first element with that tag name, not a list of them.

Comment: This would return collection of all the try elements of tbody.

Comment: that seemed to work fine :) but var cols = rows[i].find('td'); did not, chrome says find is not a function here.

Answer (score 0):

`body` is a jQuery object, not a DOM element:

```
var calendar = $('#Trafikkalender');
var body = calendar.find('tbody');
```

... so it doesn't have a `rows` property:

```
> console.log(body.rows);
undefined
```

Since you are already using jQuery you can fetch all items at once with a jQuery selector:

```
 body("td")
```

And if you prefer raw DOM elements you can extract them from the jQuery object:

```
 body[0].rows
```